# Uploading large files with Brettle Neatupload, but found a possible Intelligencia.UrlRewriter conflict?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, url-rewriting, asyncfileupload

I have been working on a project which requires large files to be uploaded (high res images, and videos etc). Windows website on IIS6 and dev on IIS7.

I am used to using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter for URL rewriting and this has worked brilliantly for me in on other projects.

I created a small test website to test NeatUpload and this worked really well, and once I'd figured out how to add some jQuery and more interesting formatting worked well.

However, once I copied the new code into the real web site the page failed with a HTTP Error:

HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

I read the manual and tried the suggested fixes to I did not get any joy.

Has anyone come across this conflict before, or found a work around or solution?

Or if it is a non-starter, are there any other (non-flash) based 3rd party solutions I can use for uploading large files? I have wasted 3 days so far and I am starting to lose patience. :-(

Cheers
Toby

Answer (score 0):

This link has the solution to the problem:

http://deepeshsomani.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/how-to-resolve-file-size-error-for-files-whose-size-is-larger-than-specified-in-web-config/

Faced the same issue and resolved it using the same approach after a week spent like hell for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is not uploading large files, I have used Neatupload for that and this works pretty well. The error is a conflict between Neatupload and the URL rewriting. If I try rewriting a nice URL like www.domain.com/upload/ to point to a file www.domain.com/uploader.aspx the page will fail and show the above error, without the url re-writing the file uploads. The issue has delayed the project, so I have used real URL's and Neatupload as a workaround and when I get time, I will build a new module/handler to deal with this.